# How do I make my tkinter image pop not show the tkinter option window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple code that opens an exe. This exe makes a pop-up image using Tkinter but there is an option to delete or minimise the photo. How do I get rid of this option?

[image]

here is my code 
and here is the TK option I was talking about

[![enter image description here]

and here is the TK option I was talking about
[image]

Comment: Hi @Jefrey could you post the text of your code here please, rather than an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

**CODE_1: where it will show minize, maximize and exit but it will not work**

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Grand Canyon")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
#window.overrideredirect(1)
window.attributes('-disabled', True)
window.resizable(0,0)
window.mainloop()
```

**CODE_2: where it will NOT show minize, maximize and exit because it will pack into the top of your window**

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Grand Canyon")
canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
window.overrideredirect(1)
#window.attributes('-disabled', True)
window.resizable(0,0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: WOW!!, thanks that fixed it. One again a stack overflow user making my day thanks!!!.

Comment: so check my answer then to validate it

Comment: Hey, Rafael, before you go do you know how I can change the pop-up locations of these images. For example, one pops up in the left and one pops up in the right.

Comment: raise another post

Comment: Hi yes, I already have one posted could you possibly check it out, please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60298656/how-do-i-set-tkinker-images-to-specific-locations